# How to deal with classes that only change a little from one another

Tags: python-3.x

I have a base class and multiple other classes that usually only fiddle with the initialization arguments.

```
class BaseClass:
    def __init__(a = 10, b = True, c = True):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
    # all the functions follow after here


class ClassA(BaseClass):
    def __init__():
        super(BaseClass, self).__init__(a=200)
    # nothing else after here


class ClassB(BaseClass):
    def __init__():
        super(BaseClass, self).__init__(b=False)
    # nothing else after here


class ClassC(BaseClass):
    def __init__():
        super(BaseClass, self).__init__(c=False)
    # nothing else after here
```

Is there a better way to deal with this than the one above?

Comment: Do you actually *need* separate classes? As shown, just having separate functions that construct the same ``BaseClass`` should work.

Comment: You forgot to pass the `self` argument in all the __init__() functions of the derived classes.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi No need to even have "constructor" functions. The arguments are already there in `__init__`. Just need to provide different values like in my answer

Comment: @DeepSpace I was under the impression that the values should be "encapsulated", whereas your answer requires the calling code to know the values.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why these are separate classes to begin with. The whole point of having arguments is that they are customizable.

```
class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self, a=10, b=True, c=True):
    #             ^  note that you forgot to pass self
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

a_instance = BaseClass(a=200)
b_instance = BaseClass(b=False)
c_instance = BaseClass(c=False)
```

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it :(

Comment: I don't either, but I'm afraid I can't change that, that's why I didn't like what I was seeing in the first place. The different classes with the different names must stay. Each of those classes is like some sort of a building block that other people can use to create their own algorithms. Maybe if I have a better pattern I can argue towards it, but I don't think saying that variables are customizable is gonna go far.

Comment: @dearn44 Then I fail to see what sort of an outcome you expected from asking this question. You asked for a better way. That is the better (and the only acceptable, to be honest) way to do what you showed

Comment: If you don't ask you will never know I guess. I was searching around and found another surprisingly "big" project that apparently needs to do something similar [ https://github.com/mementum/backtrader/blob/master/backtrader/commissions ]

Comment: @dearn44 That code is using class attributes. It is not equivalent to the example in this question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to pass `self` to all the **init**() functions in the derived classes.

Next, if it's just a single variable that you want to change, you could simply create objects of the same `BaseClass` and then pass the parameter that you to change.

```
a = BaseClass(a=200)
b = BaseClass(b=False)
c = BaseClass(c=False)
```